# Create Delta Table Using differents Periods

Tags: python, azure-databricks

I want to create a single Delta table, with the files from different folders (locations/Periods) and when automating them, it should take the files from the new periods.
Can this be done?

Period = 20220705 (Year-Month-day). Since this will automatically generate a folder for each day, the files inside this folder must be in the Delta table.

Thank you

Regards
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you please edit the question to clarify about what you mean by **new periods**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want a single delta table and you have files dated in folders as `yyyyMMdd` format and want to add files generated each day to your delta table, you can use the following approach.

- The following is a sample of files that I have in my storage account. Consider `20220707` has delta parquet files received today and `20220706` was received yesterday.

[image]

- In your databricks workspace, you want to add files to one table which indicates that they have the same schema. So, create a delta table first.

```
spark.sql("create table if not exists example (id string, firstname string, lastname string) using delta location 'dbfs:/FileStore/tables/my_data'") 

#create if exists helps to create the table only once
#so while running the notebook every day it does not throw an error
  
from delta import * 
from delta.tables import DeltaTable 
  
print(DeltaTable.isDeltaTable(spark, 'dbfs:/FileStore/tables/my_data')) 
# True 
 
spark.sql("select * from default.example").show() 

+---+---------+--------+
| id|firstname|lastname|
+---+---------+--------+
+---+---------+--------+
```

- Now that we have created the delta table, we can now use the delta parquet files to populate these tables. Since the delta folder in the container is named in the format `yyyyMMdd`, and a new folder appears for everyday (This new data should be added to delta table) we can get the current date, format it to `yyyyMMdd` structure and then we can proceed further.

```
#to get current date.

from datetime import date 
  
date_required = date.today() 
print(date_required) 
 #2022-07-07 
 
name_required = date_required.strftime('%Y%m%d') 
print(delta_required) 
#20220707
```

- Now we got the name of the folder containing all the parquet data. Create a path new period folder and insert data from its files to your delta table.

```
path = '/mnt/repro/' + name_required 
  
query = "insert into example select * from delta.`" + path + "`" 
# insert into example select * from delta.`/mnt/repro/20220707`
spark.sql(query)
```

- This will insert the data into your delta table. The output will be as following:

[image]

- As you get a new period every day, you can schedule this notebook to run at a particular time every day. There is a `Schedule` option in the top right corner of the notebook which you can use.

[image]